# Sending immediate notification with options

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

So I have a timer using AlarmManager and once it hits 0 I want it to send a notification with various attributes depending on what the user chooses (vibrate or not, play sound or not, show text or not, show... rectangle thingy in the drop-down tray whatever it's called, etc).

I am not sure what the expected class to use here is since it's immediate, i.e. it's after the alarm manager has already hit 0 and I am now in the onReceive() method of my broadcast receiver, so I don't think I need to use a PendingIntent at this point.

Do I use `NotificationCompat.Builder`? Will it do everything I need? And if so do I use the support v4 or v7 version?

Trying this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
    .setContentText("This text should be in notification drawer!");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
Toast.makeText(c, "Toast text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Yes NotificationCompat.Builder will do all of the above things you need

Comment: @kapsym Which version should I be using? v4 or v7?

Comment: That depends on your other functionalities of the app. both support above Android 2.3 but v7 has additional components like action bar and stuff. v7 internally uses v4 so I guess you can use v7 to get all v4 features plus more that it offers

Comment: @kapsym How do I use the builder do to all the above listed things? I don't see things in the builder like ringtone or notification dropdown or text. And how do I launch it immediately? is `.build();` enough?

Comment: Nvm I think I have to use this notification manager thing, can I just make the ID 1?

Comment: yes .build is enough. And if you want to set a specific time you can use .setWhen as well. You can find all methods related to action that you need to do here -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: Id and tag should be unique tou your application so that you can cancel it if you want at later stage. it could be 1 to anything

Comment: @kapsym I added more text to my post. Am I setting the icons wrong? The big icon seems to work but small icon is greyed out even though it's the same icon ID?

Comment: That icon should be small in size to show perfectly. If you dont have a small icon size in drawable it can get greyed out. Check for size guidelines :)

Comment: Also I am adding my comments as an answer so that you can accept it :)

Comment: @kapsym Was just about to say, please do, definitely deserves an accept

Comment: Thanks for accepting. PS do add your name in the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments -

Yes `NotificationCompat.Builder` will do all of the above things you need. 
.build is enough to send notification instantly. And if you want to set a specific time you can use .setWhen as well. You can find all methods related to action that you need to do here - [Notification Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)